# Ansible: Combining lists from a registered variable

Tags: ansible

So I have a playbook that creates ec2 instances one in each az. So we have 3 creations of instances in this example. From this I can register the output of the creation of this instance as a variable and later use it's data to access information about the instance I created like ip address etc... My issue is when trying to create a dynamic hosts entry I cannot set three dynamic hosts entries from all three results as they all override the previous set. So my question is is there anyway to just combine all of the results into a single dynamic hosts entry? Or even to just combine all the results into a single dictionary like multiple json objects or something of the like?

Answer (score 0):

Use [add_hosts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/add_host_module.html) and add the ip_address to a group. Don't worry about overwriting. New hosts will be added to the group. Extract the ip_address from the registered variable and keep appending to your group.

```
- add_host: name={{ ip_from_ec2 }} groups=my_hosts
```